# static 2d array, adding elements

Tags: c++, arrays

My problem is in adding elements. If I tried to add again it's just replacing the last add position. where when adding, it supposed to be moving to the next slot/index.

for example

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0| a  b  c  d  e  f
1| g  h  i  j  k  l
2| 

Add element:m

 0  1  2  3  4  5
0| a  b  c  d  e  f
1| g  h  i  j  k  l
2| m
```

Add element:n

```
0  1  2  3  4  5
0| a  b  c  d  e  f
1| g  h  i  j  k  l
2| m  n
```

here is my code:

```
  #include<iostream>
    #include<string>

    std::string myarray[3][6] = {{"a","b","c","d","e","f"},
                                {"g","h","i","j","k","l"},
                                {" "," "," "," "," "," "}}; 


    void display();

    using namespace std;

    int main(){

    while(true){

        display();

        char add;
        int rows = 2;
        int cols = 6;

        cout<<"==========================================" <<endl;
        cout<<"Add element: ";
        cin>>add;

        int size = rows*cols;
        myarray[0][size] = add;

        cout<<"Adding Successful!" <<endl;

        size=size+1;
    }

    }

    //display
    void display(){

        cout<<endl;
        for(int z = 0; z<6; z++){
            cout<<"  "<<z;
        }
        cout<<endl;

        for(int x = 0; x<3; x++){
        cout<<x <<"|";
            for(int y = 0; y<6; y++){
                cout<<" " <<myarray[x][y] <<" "; 
            }
        cout<<endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can't add elements to an array.

Comment: The allocated array `myarray[3][6]` has 3 rows with 6 columns. But unfortunately you accessed `myarray[0][size]` with `size>=12`. But your first row has not 13 or more elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always the element `myarray[0][size]` is assigned a new value where in each iteration a new `int size = rows*cols;`is calculated (`size` = 12). And your are accessing the Array out of ist limits

Without any of the other issues taking into account this might be fixed:

```
int col=0;
while (col < 6) {
    display();

    char add;

    cout<<"==========================================" <<endl;
    cout<<"Add element: ";
    cin>>add;

    myarray[2][col] = add;

    cout<<"Adding Successful!" <<endl;

    ++col;
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. "accessing the Array out of its limits"  <- but i already made some allowance in size since its real size is [3][6]? is this not a valid way in static array?

Comment: Depends on how the compiler lays out the memory allocation - you will have a dependency you should NEVER rely on.

An 2-dimensional array of 3 x 6 is not a 1-dimensional array of 18 values. Accessing an array out of bounds is undefined behavior. It might be that the compiler does memory alignment for each start each rows. It might be that it works for one pompiler or processor architecture but not for another. Simply: stay in the ranges of each dimension and rely on well-defined behaviour.

Comment: so the safest way in dealing with static array is to transfer it into another array with bigger size? thanks again, i'll keep this in my mind.

Comment: The safest way is to stay inside the ranges defined - independen of the number of dimensions. Each Dimension needs to stay in it's range. If you have an array of 18 elements and access the 19th you will have the same undefined behaviour.
In your case `myarray[3][6]` only `array[row][col]` with `0<=row<3`and `0<=col<6`are admissible. (Take care, range is half-open, upper range Limit not included).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is int his part of code

```
int rows = 2;

    int cols = 6;

cout<<"==========================================" <<endl;
cout<<"Add element: ";
cin>>add;

int size = rows*cols;
myarray[0][size] = add
```

;

You need something like ++rows or ++cols and call

```
myarray[rows][cols] = add
```

Comment: thanks for replying. i already did the ++rows and ++ cols and its still no changes in the output